# Genesis 3:16 Does God make them suffer?

Tags: genesis, judgement

In Genesis 3:16 does the Hebrew actually reveal God saying 'I WILL (greatly increase your pains)?  Is there any query in the Hebrew about God causing them pain as opposed to God simply foretelling the suffering that the woman and man have brought on themselves??

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this realted answer: [What does Genesis 3:16 literally say?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/what-does-genesis-316-literally-say?rq=1)

He is saying that the pain during child birth will be greatly multiplied.  He is the one that caused the pain to multiply.  In the direct Hebrew he says that He will "greatly multiply" pain in conception: http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/3-16.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case I think this is actually a duplicate since the other post answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @Daи Since it wasn't marked yet I was unsure of whether to answer or not.  I answered only because it was still open.  I hope I don't get downvoted for doing so.

Comment: *au contraire*, you earned my upvote ;) - in the future, note that you can also flag the question and when you have enough rep you'll be able to vote to close as a duplicate as well. Thanks for answering and pointing out where the OP can get more information - this answer is helpful.